# LAMP modules - the necessities

Tags: ubuntu

I've got a fresh install of LAMP and I have Suhosinand xCache.  What else would you recommend I setup and use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than installing more and more components you should rather invest some time and configure the ones you've already installed in a sane way.

Comment: I've gone and googled configuration suggestions for xcache and didn't have much luck finding anything that was awesome....